# Invalid query: cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql

I think that I have a problem with my insert statement with a subquery select statement this would be my code:

```
INSERT INTO location_dim( address, clinic_id, dentist_id ) 

SELECT '$_POST[txbAddress]','$_POST[ClinicNameSelect]', 
(
   SELECT dentist_id
   FROM dentist_dim
   WHERE dentist_email =  '$_POST[txbEmail]'
)
```

Comment: I am not sure if the quoting is correct or incorrect

Comment: Show the ddl please.

Comment: use $_POST['txbAddress'] in single quotes

Comment: apart from the missing quotes that satish rajak pointed out: could you elaborate a bit on what kind of problem you have, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please provide some sample data of the existing tables, and the result you're trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax should be following INSERT INTO myTable(a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3);
Quotes inside brackets

My try would be this

```
INSERT INTO location_dim(address, clinic_id, dentist_id)
VALUES ($_POST['txbAddress'], $_POST['ClinicNameSelect'], 
(
SELECT dentist_id 
FROM dentist_dim 
WHERE dentist_email = $_POST['txbEmail']
)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

$sql = 'INSERT INTO location_dim(address, clinic_id, dentist_id)
VALUES (
SELECT ' . $_POST['txbAddress'] . ', ' . $_POST['ClinicNameSelect'] . ', 
dentist_id 
FROM dentist_dim 
WHERE dentist_email = ' . $_POST['txbEmail'] . '
);';